# $\prod_{k \in Q}{\frac{k^2-1}{k^2+1}}$ is rational number for $Q \subset N$

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, irrational-numbers, products

Let's consider some subset of natural numbers $Q$ and product:
$$\prod_{k \in Q}{\frac{k^2-1}{k^2+1}}$$

There is well known theorem that if $Q$ is the set of prime numbers than the above product is rational and
$$\prod_{p \in P}{\frac{p^2-1}{p^2+1}}=\frac{2}{5}$$
Can be found in: https://mathworld.wolfram.com/PrimeProducts.html

Actually the question is, **is there any other known infinite subset of natural numbers which brings us to rational value, except the prime/composite numbers**.

Some more examples:
If $Q=N_n = \{t n ~ |~n \in N  ~\& ~t \in N\}$ then
$$\prod_{k \in N_n}{\frac{k^2-1}{k^2+1}} = \sin \left(\frac{\pi }{n}\right) \text{csch}\left(\frac{\pi }{n}\right)$$

and most probably those values are irrational as of $e^\pi$.

Comment: "More or less obvious"?! I don't think so. (Also, a link to your well-known theorem would be nice.)

Comment: Agree, let me edit the question.

Comment: Let treat this as an exception:) As it is obvious.

Comment: As best I can tell, your link doesn't discuss arbitrary $Q\subseteq\Bbb P$.

Comment: @J.G. sorry did not get,  could you please clarify a bit your comment?

Comment: I think J.G. is complaining that "$Q$ is a set of prime numbers" should be "$Q$ is _the_ set of prime numbers".

Comment: @Troposphere Thank you for clarification, yes that is true, sorry for my English, let me correct.

Comment: Are you looking specifically for subsets of $\mathbb N$ that have a _nice_ description? Every real strictly between $\prod_{k=2}^\infty (k^2-1)/(k^2+1)$ (which is positive, though I don't know its exact value) and $1$ can be expressed as such a product over _some_ infinite set of naturals. (And this set will be computable if the target product is rational).

Comment: @Troposphere could you please ellaborate a bit your comment? It looks very interesting.

Comment: @Troposphere Could you please leave an answer that successfully does what my now deleted answer tried to?

Comment: @J.G. So done -- thanks for poking, that was subtler than I could ever do with comments. :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $1\in Q$, then the product is $0$ -- the $k=1$ factor kills it immediately. That's indeed an uninteresting case.

Otherwise, since each term *decreases* the product, the smallest result we can get is to include all $k\ge 2$. Now that smallest result,
$$ \alpha = \prod_{k=2}^{\infty} \frac{k^2-1}{k^2+1}, $$
is *positive*, because we can take logarithms factor for factor and get
$$ \tag{*} -\log \alpha
 = \sum_{k=2}^{\infty} \log\frac{k^2+1}{k^2-1}
 = \sum_{k=2}^{\infty} \log\Bigl(1+\frac{2}{k^2-1}\Bigr)
 < \frac{2\pi^2}{6} $$
because $\frac{1}{k^2-1} < \frac{1}{(k-1)^2} $ when $k\ge 2$, and and $\log(1+x)\le x$.

However, every real number $\beta\in(\alpha,1)$ -- and in particular every *rational* number in that interval -- can be produced by some $Q$.

All we have to do is to find a subset of the $\log(1+2/(k^2-1))$ terms that sum to $-\log \beta$. This is always possible in this case -- we can simply start from $k=2$ and select every term that doesn't make the sum *so far* too large.

There's a subtlety, however: This "greedy" procedure doesn't work for *all* series. For example, we clearly can't pick a subset of the terms in $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} 10^{-k}$ to reach an *arbitrary* number between $0$ and $0.111\ldots$.

What saves us in this case is that each term in (*) is at least half the size of the previous term. (This is easily the case asymptotically, and can be verified by direct computation for the first few terms). Thus whenever we *skip* a term because we're too close to the target, the sum of the terms we haven't considered yet will be larger than the term we skipped. Therefore the *difference* between the partial sum and our target number remains bounded by the sum of not-yet-considered terms -- and that bound goes to $0$.

---

Note that the resulting $Q$ is a *computable* subset of $\mathbb N$, as long as we can effectively compare $\beta$ to the partial products that would result if we pick a candidate term. That's clearly the case when $\beta$ is rational, and also for a large class of interesting irrational numbers. (We don't need to compute with the logarithms during the practical calculation; that was just for proving the procedure gives the right result).

**For example,** suppose we want to find a $Q$ where the product is exactly $\frac12$. We take the factors one by one:

- $k=2$, candidate factor $\frac{3}{5}$. We'll **include** this factor. The partial product so far is $\frac{3}{5}$.
- $k=3$, candidate factor $\frac{8}{10}$. If we include this factor the product would be $\frac{3}{5}\cdot\frac{8}{10}=\frac{24}{50}$, which is too small. So we **skip** it.
- $k=4$, candidate factor $\frac{15}{17}$. If we this factor, the partial product becomes $\frac{3}{5}\cdot\frac{15}{17} = \frac{9}{17}$, which is $>\frac12$, so **include** this factor.
- $k=5$, candidate factor $\frac{24}{26}$. Partial product would be $\frac{9}{17}\cdot\frac{24}{26} = \frac{216}{442}$, which is too small. **Skip**.
- $k=6$, candidate factor $\frac{35}{37}$, new partial product $\frac{9}{17}\cdot\frac{35}{37} = \frac{315}{629}$, just barely over $\frac12$. **Include.**
- $k=7$, candidate factor $\frac{48}{50}$, new partial product would be $\frac{315\cdot 48}{629\cdot 50}=\frac{15120}{31450} < \frac12$. **Skip.**
- ... all factors end up skipped until ...
- $k=35$, new partial product would be $\frac{315\cdot1224}{629\cdot1226} = \frac{385560}{771154} < \frac12$ so **skip.**
- $k=36$, new partial product would be $\frac{315\cdot1295}{629\cdot1297} = \frac{407925}{815813} = \frac{11025}{22049} > \frac12$, so **include**.

The next included factor ends up being for $k=210$. Continuing this way, we find $Q=\{2,4,6,36, 210, 44100, \ldots\}$, so
$$ \frac12 = \frac{2^2-1}{2^2+1} \times \frac{4^2-1}{4^2+1} \times \frac{6^2-1}{6^2+1} \times
\frac{36^2-1}{36^2+1} \times \frac{210^2-1}{210^2+1} \times
\frac{44100^2-1}{44100^2+1} \times \cdots $$
This is by far not the only $Q$ that produces $\frac12$, though.

Comment: Thanks, could you please show how this idea works for $2/5$?

Comment: @GevorgHmayakyan We never find a need to skip, but the resulting product, while having partial products greater than it's limit, has limit we can prove is $\zeta(4)/[\zeta(2)]^2=2/5$.

Comment: @J.G. Thank you for your comment, sorry again did not get the answer details.

Comment: @GevorgHmayakyan: Note that there are generally many _different_ $Q$ sets where the product has the same limit. I don't expect the procedure I describe here will end up selecting exactly the primes if we use _it_ to reach $2/5$.

Comment: @GevorgHmayakyan: I've added a concrete example of the calculations.

Comment: Very nice. Thank you!

Comment: Just one question. This algorithm defines the unique sequence based on the first element. Am I missing something here?

Comment: @GevorgHmayakyan: There's nothing unique about the $Q$ found by this algorithm. In most cases we could easily get away with waiting a bit more before we include a factor -- for example we could find a $Q$ that starts as $\{2,4,6,127,\ldots\}$ instead of $\{2,4,6,36,\ldots\}$. However, knowing _just how far_ you can get away with waiting is not easy -- you'd need to know the infinite product of all the factors you haven't gotten to yet, and I don't know a way to compute that exactly. Taking a new term as soon as you can is a convenient way to prove that _some_ solutions always _exist_, though.

Comment: @Troposphere thank you got your point, but I think there would be  the set with min values. Which looks interesting. Is this something that would make sense to dig deeper?

Comment: @GevorgHmayakyan: It's true that this procedure will produce the _lexicographically smallest_ increasing sequence of $k$s that hit the desired product.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming your prime statement is true, then any set with the primes and a finite number of composites would also be rational.

Comment: Actually this is a good point, but the idea of question is to find any other subsets of natural numbers, not the prime or composite.

Comment: These truly are other subsets. This answer points out that one should really consider equivalence classes of subsets under the equivalence of having finite symmetric difference, because any two such equivalent subsets obviously generate either both rational products or both irrational products.

Comment: @GregMartin agree and thank you for valuable comment.